# Working with DatabaseHelper while recreating activity on Android

Tags: android, database, android-activity, lifecycle

I have an activity that uses AsyncTask to download and save some data to the database. To open a database we need to pass Context param to the SQLiteOpenHelper's onCreate method, which means that database somehow needs context.

And I'm just curious, what would happen when device turns and activity goes through destroy and create cycle? Is it ok to open database in activity's constructor rather than in activity's onCreate() method?

The problem is that I use DB from another thread and I want to know what exactly would happen when activity is being destroyed and recreated

Comment: you must override onDestroy() method and here close your db object.

Comment: But if I do so, the background thread, that should save downloaded data to the database, will crash. Is there a way to let it finish its job and then close db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use the ApplicationContext instead of the ActivityContext. You only need a static method that requests the ApplicationContext from the Application constructor.

If you use some kind of singleton to access the context, you won't have any problems with concurrency.

See example here: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1218

Another approach would be to use the LoaderManager which keeps track of your opened database connections.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html
(There is a complete example too)

The LoaderManager is available in the compatibility package for down to Android 1.5

Michael

Comment: Thank you, Michael! I guess, that's what i was looking for. Sorry, can't vote up

Answer (score 1):

Incase you want to do some db operations in background. you should use "Sevices".
Services can do long running operations on background.

here is the link : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: Thanks for answer! Services are good,  but my thread needs to communicate with activity when it's up, so, i think, AsyncTask suits better